# Powershell implementing checkboxes within a table of data

Tags: powershell, checkbox

Currently writing a PowerShell script to query DB & convert that info to a DataTable. Then output all to HTML file. I want 3 columns of the table to be outputted as checked checkboxes instead of T/F. Meaning instead of a value in table being true, it will appear as a check box.

I have tried writing a While loop to loop through the elements.

Comment: Please post your existing code and describe the exact problem you're running into